# Doesn't the Riemman series theorem imply that any real number is computable?

Tags: computability

For clarity, I'm talking about [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem). My confusion lies at the fact that we can seemingly compute any real number by re-arranging a conditionally convergent infinite series, but apparently we can't actually compute every real number, so I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you enumerate all a) programs b) inputs c real numbers? $Any \ne Every$

Comment: May be You need to be more precise in terms: $1$ is real number - we cannot compute it? I suspect you mean irrational number.

Comment: Yeah, I meant every real number; I'm aware of the diagonal argument, but I'm not sure where my reasoning goes wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can permute the terms of a conditionally convergent series to get a series which converges to any real value.  But the permutation needed to achieve any particular value may itself NOT be computable!

Comment: Also, you can never compute the *entire* sum, therefore - even if you could somehow compute the permutation - then  you could just *approximate* every real value to any $\epsilon>0$ error you want (which is still not computing the exact value of it)

Comment: @nirshahar Actually that *is* (one of the various equivalent definitions of) what it means to compute a real number. E.g. $\pi$ is computable since we have a computable process which, on input $n\in\mathbb{N}$, provides a (standard notation for a) rational number within $2^{-n}$ of $\pi$.